# Zoom in/out with Ctrl+ / Ctrl- not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, it seems like all the keyboard shortcuts work, except for those that zoom in/out. (I'm on Windows and using Eclipse Version "Kepler Service Release 2") I have already restored the default keys in my preferences as other StackOverflow posts have advised, but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? because in some version 'ctrl' + 'shift' + '+'/'-' works.

Comment: Using shift with ctrl +/- doesn't help.

Comment: Which Eclipse version and what is not zoomed (font size of which editor?)?

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide an answer, but you haven't really provided enough information for anyone to be confident that they are fully dealing with your problem.

It would still be useful to know what version of Eclipse you're using.

The first thing to do, is determine exactly what the binding is for the "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" commands, by looking in the "Keys" section in Preferences.  It's easiest to type "zoom" in the filter field to limit the table to those functions.  I imagine you've already effectively done this, but it is a prerequisite.

The next thing to do is look for conflicts.  There are two ways to look for this.  First, check the Eclipse log.  It will note if there is a keybinding conflict.  Second, in that same "Keys" list, remove "zoom" from the filter (if it was there) and click on the "Binding" header to sort by the key sequence.  Then page through the list until you find "Ctrl++" and "Ctrl+-" in the list, which I assume are the bindings you have.  What you want to check for is if there is another binding in that list where "Ctrl++" BEGINS the key sequence, and is longer than that.  Do the same for "Ctrl+-".

If you still don't find any clues from this, I suppose it's possible there's something else you have installed in Windows that is capturing that key sequence.  I don't know how you would check for that.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying earlier, the version of Eclipse that I have is "Kepler Service Release 2". Is this an outdated version?

Comment: @AdityaR. Kepler is now 8 years and 15 releases old, I can't remember for sure but I think the zoom was added in one of those newer releases. Eclipse 2020-12 is the current release.

Comment: Oh wow! How do I update my Eclipse version?

Comment: Go to https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and download new fancy installer. It will help you to install and maintain eclipse releases.